# how to create a link in a google spreadsheet cell to reveal a local file in Mac Finder

Tags: mac, google-sheets

I want to be able to click on a link in a google spreadsheet and reveal a local folder / file in finder and I will create multiple links of this kind in one spreadsheet for this purpose. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: I very much doubt this is possible. It would be a security nightmare. Windows used to support `file://` links but macOS never has.